# Can you allocate a big memory block to your vector when initializing them in C++

Tags: c++

I instantiated a string vector and tried to put a binary file of size 10kb inside it, but it corrupted the stack of one of my variable and the program crashed. I was wondering if I could allocate a big memory block when instantiating it instead of making it grow and possibly corrupt contiguous memory blocks that are already used.

Comment: Wait, you created a string vector for a binary file? perhaps tell us what the problem you are trying to solve is, because this just doesn't make sense...

Comment: If you are storing the contents of a binary file in a vector of strings my advice is don't do that.

Comment: I second @MattCoubrough, if you want to store a binary file use a vector of bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if I could allocate a big memory block when instantiating it

Yes you can; [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

> instead of making it grow and possibly corrupt contiguous memory blocks that are already used.

If you grow the vector properly by resizing or inserting/pushing elements, it will never corrupt memory. If the vector grows too large to fit in the already allocated memory, the memory manager will find a bigger chunk of contiguous memory and move your vector there.

Comment: Are you sure it never happens? I get an error message that says "vector subscript out of range".